# app script to copy row of data to different spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-sheets

Is it possible to copy a row of data from one google sheet workbook or spreadsheet to a different google sheet or spreadsheet using app script?  I have been able to copy a row of data from sheet to sheet within a workbook or spreadsheet but not to a different workbook.

Answer (score 0):

no, it is not posible to copy from one sheet to another..

[image]